# How Split method and spaces in python helped in changing positions of letters?

Tags: python, indexing, split

So there is this code here, the solution is written but I cannot get my head around it. How the 'say' variable got assigned the texts in that order with only spaces and indices. and what is the role of that split method up above. Even though I have understood the list methods very well, but the solution is fuzzy to me. Any clarifications? .

The Question:

> Let's create a function that turns text into pig latin: a simple text
> transformation that modifies each word moving the first character to
> the end and appending "ay" to the end. For example, python ends up as
> ythonpay.

The code:

```
def pig_latin(text):
    say = ""
    # Separate the text into words
    words = text.split (' ')
    for word in words:
        # Create the pig latin word and add it to the list
        say += word[1:]+word[0]+'ay '
    # Turn the list back into a phrase
    return say
        
print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun")) # Should be "rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay"
```

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split documentation https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split

slice documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice

```py
a = "String that will be splited using space"
# split methos is used to create list from string,
# in the split we specify 'sep' parameter that is used as delimiter to separate the string
print("Split:", a.split(' '))
b = a.split(' ')
s = ''  # empty string
for i in b:
    # the slice operation in string and list is based on index
    print("Slice:", i[1:], i[0], i[1:]+i[0]+'ay ')
    s += i[1:]+i[0]+'ay '
print("Final string:", s)
```